# Does MongoDB InsertMany returns both the successfully inserted and failed documents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We're using MongoDB insertMany() and I'd like to get both the successfully inserted documents with the failed ones.

Some of the documents fail to be inserted since we first put the ones that are unique (by PhoneNumber) and after that if the code encounters the same PhoneNumber then it adds the string `DUP` to the phoneNumber.

The code :

```
try {
       await Leads.insertMany(leadsToInsert, {
        ordered: false
      });

}

catch(err) {

 if (err.code === 11000) {
        // Here we get the errors 
        const ordersIDsWithDuplicates = err.result.result.writeErrors;
 }

}
```

In the catch block we get the documents that failed.

Is there a way to get the documents that we successfully inserted , at the same time without querying the DB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's under `insertedIds` on the same level with `writeErrors`:

```
{
  "name":"BulkWriteError",
  "driver":true,
  "code":11000,
  "writeErrors":[ ... ],
  "writeConcernErrors":[ ... ],
  "insertedIds":[{"index":0,"_id":7085598},{"index":1,"_id":7085599} ... ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's 3 years later but this post helped me solve my problem. inserMany() also returns all the succesfully created documents. The try/catch will show if we have any real errors pop up.

```
try {
      const result = await User.insertMany(operations, { ordered: false })
      result.forEach( document => {
        console.log('document', document)
      } )
    } catch (e) {
      e.writeErrors.forEach(function (err) {
        if (err.code != 11000) {
          // real error!                                                  
          throw e;
        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of when after execution will show the ones in console why the errors and details:

```
const taskCollection = db.collection("task");
try {
    const docs = [
        { _id: 1, description: "Clean the house", completed: true },
        { _id: 2, description: "Clean the house", completed: true },
        { _id: 1, description: "Go pick up mail", completed: false },
        { _id: 4, description: "Check email", completed: false },
        { _id: 4, description: "Check email", completed: false },
        { _id: 2, description: "Clean the house", completed: true },
        { _id: 45, description: "Check email", completed: false },
    ];

    const options = { ordered: false };

    const insertManyresult = await taskCollection.insertMany(docs, options);
    let ids = insertManyresult.insertedIds;

    console.log(
        `${insertManyresult.insertedCount} documents were inserted`
    );

    for (let id of Object.values(ids)) {
        console.log(`Inserted a document with id ${id}`);
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log(
        `A MongoBulkWriteException occurred, but there are successfully processed documents.`
    );
    console.log(e.result.result);
    for(let obj of Object.values(e.result.result.writeErrors)){
        console.log(obj.err)
    }
    
}
```